# Cannot use RabbitMQ shovel to migrate messages to another instance which is not using the shovel plugin

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I'm trying to migrate messages from a queue with Shovel from a RabbitMQ instance that is using Shovel to another one which has the previous version of rmq and is not supporting the Shovel plugin.

When the Shovel is created, I'm getting a log for successfull connection on the rmq instance with the old version which do not support Shovel plugin but the messages are not migrated.
If I'm trying to migrate the messages into the same new instance where Shovel is installed, it works.

Do you know if it is an intended restriction? Or I'm doing something wrong?

From the documentation I could not find any relevant information if the destination of the Shovel need to have also the Shovel plugin installed or has any version restriction.